# Global Decorator in Storybook for Vanilla HTML Project

Tags: storybook

I have a HTML (not React, Svelte, etc...) Storybook project and am trying to set a global decorator. When trying to define the decorator, according to the Storybook docs, I am getting the attached error. Doing the same in a Svelte project works just fine.

I'm tending to believe that the HTML `Decorator` isn't working the same as the others, and the docs haven't caught up.

How can I customize my global decorator in this configuration of Storybook?

[image]